# Updating a foreground service notification using a Timer that works even when the device is in Doze/Sleep mode

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, foreground-service

I have a Timer (System.Timers) which is wrapped into an object that exposes two events. One that fires every second, and one that fires every 7 minutes. The event that fires every second, is updating a foreground service notification with a countdown. The event that fires every 7 minutes is updating an int value which is shown in a progress bar on that foreground notification.

The point is that I want that int value to reach 150. so I am counting down how long it will take for the value which is given at the time of StartForeground() to reach 150 (which increases by 1 every 7 minutes) and showing the progress in the foreground notification with a time remaining (updated every second).

This all works fine... until i lock the screen and the phone presumably goes into "doze" or sleep mode. this then stops my timer or stops the service, not sure.

**Question**: How can I make this carry on working even if the device is locked/sleeping/dozed. I am using xamarin-android not forms.

Comment: You can use a wake lock https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#:~:text=Wake%20locks%20allow%20your%20application%20to%20control%20the,them%20for%20as%20short%20a%20time%20as%20possible. (also is your timer code in your foregrounded service?)

Comment: Could it work ?

Comment: @SushiHangover thank you, your suggestion to use a wake lock is what worked! If you write it as an answer ill mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the application to the whitelist.

You could use `PowerManager.IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations` check whether this App in the system of the white list.

If not, you can apply for the permission by adding `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission to the `Androidmanifest.xml` and sending an `Intent` of `ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS`.

For example:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
if (!powerManager.IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(PackageName))
   {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ActionIgnoreBatteryOptimizationSettings);
      StartActivity(intent);
   }
```